# HashTable remove function C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am very new to C++ and I am working on creating a program using HashTables. This is for homework. This is the first time I am using and creating HashTables, so forgive me in advance as to I don't know entirely what I am doing. The main problem I am having right now is incorporating my `remove()` function. I can get the code to compile, but when I run test the program out, it crashes. The **error** that I am receiving is

> list iterator is not decrementable

I am basing my remove function off of an insert function my professor provided us with. Just changed a few things around. Here is my class `HTable` and my `remove()` function.

```
class HTable
{
public:
    HTable(int size);
    void insert(  const string &s);
    void remove(string key);

private:
    vector<list<string>> List;
    int currSize;
    int tableSize;
    int hash(const string &key);
    int hashFunction(string key);
    int HTableSize;
    int *status_arr;
    ostream &   operator <<( ostream &);
};
```

`remove()` function

```
inline void HTable::remove(string key)
{
    list<string> List;

    if( find( List.begin( ), List.end( ), key )  ==  List.begin( ) )
    {
        List.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: always removing the end item seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Since you're already using `STL` just use `std::remove_if()` instead of `std::find()`.

Comment: Also, your `list<string> List;` object being local to the `remove()` function -- is that just a copy/paste error into your question?  That object obviously will have no contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline void HTable::remove( string key)
{
   list<string> List;

   if( find( List.end( ), List.begin( ), key )  ==  List.begin( ) )
   {         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     List.pop_back();
   }

}
```

You should put `List.begin()` before `List.end()` if you use `find` algorithm according to prototype of find:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
```

Meanwhile:

`first, last
Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a sequence. The range searched is [first,last), which contains all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the element pointed by last.`

Besides, your find condition is wrong:

```
 if( find( List.begin( ), List.end( ), key )  !=  List.end( ) )
 {                                            //^^^^^
    //if key exist, remove
 }
```

In your code, it will keep removing until local `List` is empty.

Your remove function should look this the following:

```
 inline void HTable::remove( string key)
 {
   vector<list<string> >::iterator it;
   for ( it = List.begin(); it != List.end(); it ++)
   {

     if( find( (*it).begin( ), (*it).end( ), key )  !=  (*it).end( ) )
     {
        (*it).pop_back();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: oops, I forgot to change that around. I was trying something else. But even when I put List.begin() first, I still receive that same error

Comment: ok, awesome! i tried that and it works, but I just feel as if with this code, I am not removing anything.

Comment: @bobGlenn you should not remove from your local List, but should remove from the List member of the class.

Comment: with the code I have right now with the pop.back(), i am removing from my local list?

Comment: @bobGlenn Yes. since you declared `list<string> List;` inside the remove function.

Comment: Ok, then I am unsure of how to remove from the List member of the class

Comment: @bobGlenn your class member is a vector of lists of strings, first go through the vector, then go through the current list, if you find the key in current list, remove it. The same as you did for single list, just add another loop to go through the vectors

Comment: I see what you are saying, but unfortunately I can't seem to turn that into coding. I'm sorry. I'm still very new to c++

Comment: @bobGlenn try my updated post? I was out, so sorry for late reply.

Comment: no problem at all tacp. the program does work. but I believe that my insert function is wrong. the teacher just provided a sample output as to what the program is to supposed to look like, and mine looks nothing like it. Believe it is my insert(). could i follow the same format as the remove() ?

Comment: @bobGlenn to insert, you basically first insert into list of strings, then push back this list of string into vector.

Comment: @bobGlenn you cannot simply follow the same format, the reason is that remove works because your List has stuff in it. insert is actually simply, first push strings into the list, then push back theses lists into vector of lists, i.e., List.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm being a pain and not able to understand this. programming gets me aggravated. i can see it visually what you are saying, but i am terrible at translating it into coding. i only have the prototype of the function, but cannot translate the wording into code to put inside of the function. the prototype i have is `void insert( const string &s )`

Answer (score 0):

Use rbegin and rend to get reverse iterators if you want to traverse list backward (if you need this, yes - sometimes it might be better, faster: depends on context):

```
for (std::list<...>::reverse_iterator it=list.rbegin(); it!=list.rend(); ++it)
```

you can also use auto:

`for( auto it=list.rend(); it!=list.rbegn(); ++it ) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing from your list by finding an exact value, it's easier to let the standard template library help you.

For C++98, create a predicate object that will check for equality of your objects:

```
struct string_equal
{
   string_equal(const std::string& tgt) : target(tgt)
   {}

   bool operator()(const std::string& key) const
   {
      return key == target;
   }

   const std::string& target;
};

void remove(const std::string& key)
{
   // find the appropriate list in your vector
   list<string>& List = get_correct_list_for_key(key);

   list<string>::iterator new_end = std::remove_if(List.begin(), List.end(), string_equal(key));

   List.erase(new_end, List.end());
}
```

In C++11, you can do this even easier using a lambda:

```
void remove(const std::string& key)
{
   list<string>& List = get_correct_list_for_key(key);

   auto new_end = std::remove_if(List.begin(), List.end(),
     [&] (const std::string& target) -> bool { return target == key; });

   List.erase(new_end, List.end());
}
```